# data.table: Identify increasing contiguous sequence in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, grouping, vectorization, sequence

I'm trying to identify a contiguous increasing sequence within a column in data.table and assign an identifier for each unique contiguous sequence groupings, but I'm having a difficult time coming up with a vectorized way to quickly identify these sequences.

I've looked around and haven't found anything that only uses data.table syntax and commands to do this in a vectorized manner, maybe perhaps it's not possible.

```r
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(ID=c(1,1,1,1),time=c(17,18,74,75),exposure=c(0,1,1,1))
```

My data looks like this:

```r
   ID time exposure
1:  1   17        0
2:  1   18        1
3:  1   74        1
4:  1   75        1
```

and I want to create a new column that indicates which rows for `time` that are a contiguous increasing sequence, like so:

```r
   ID time exposure contiguous.groups
1:  1   17        0                x1
2:  1   18        1                x1
3:  1   74        1                x2
4:  1   75        1                x2
```

If anyone has done this before or has an idea of how to begin, your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can take the `diff` of adjacent element of 'time' to create a logical vector and get the cumulative sum

```
DT[, contiguous.groups := paste0("x", cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(time) != 1)))]
DT
#   ID time exposure contiguous.groups
#1:  1   17        0                x1
#2:  1   18        1                x1
#3:  1   74        1                x2
#4:  1   75        1                x2
```

Comment: thank you so much!! This is very neat and extremely useful

Comment: @akrun I was almost there with `group := cumsum( c(0, diff(time)-1))` but you beat me to it